# Best way to organize and copy resources in this Maven PHP project

Tags: maven

I am thinking of what would be the best way to organize and copy certain resources and i am looking for some suggestions of what would be the best approach.

I am developing a PHP application and I am using maven for managing the project (tests, dependencies, packaging etc.) I am using an external library (code igniter, a PHP MVC framework) which offers an up-to-date [stable version through github](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/tree/2.1-stable). (In this case I am interested in the github version because it contains some fixes that have not been released yet for download from the website.)

Everytime I compile/package the application, I would like to retrieve a copy from github (or used a locally cached version). I did some googling on this, it doesn't seem to be that simple. I am considering to create a maven artifact for code igniter in my personal maven repository and add that as a dependency. Though this is were I started to wonder whether this is the best approach.

Some more information about the project:

- The webroot is located in src/main/webapp/
- I might decide to change the location of the webroot to something simpler for developers that are not used working with Maven, but it would be acceptable to learn the developers about Maven directory structure.
- I would like to separate the custom developed PHP files from the Code Igniter files (and overlay them before running the tests).

What is a good maven solution in this case?

Comment: I tried making a separate WAR file for CodeIgniter and overlay the WAR by adding it as a dependency in my project. It works for generating WAR files, however it fails in combination with jetty-maven-plugin, which is a blocker for me :/ Looks like I am restricted to a copy solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should ask yourselve what the main goal would be. PHP itself does not know anything about war files, nor does the (formally used) apache httpd know something about it. PHP prefers PHAR files. Did you use php-maven or did you try to solve it on your own way? Maybe you should share your work at php-maven. See google group at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/maven-for-php

You should not try to fight against maven conventions. So actually this is a maven project and the sources should be placed at src/main/webapp or src/main/php or src/main/resources (as you propably know). Leading php developers into the common maven file structure is not difficult. As PHP projects are not very intuitive (most frameworks do have their own packaging and file layout) PHP developers should be fine with learning "All sources go to src/main/php".

So to ask your questions:

1) What you are describing about code igniter actually is describing a snapshot. Maven handles snapshots very well. So the only remaining question is: How to get them imported automatically. PHP-Maven alrweady has an importer of pear projects, several web downloads and even github downloads. I think this importer could be easy driven to download snapshot builds from github. It is only a matter of how to be notified about newer versions (or which interval to look for them).

2) Dependency management is solved in PHP-Maven by either add the dependency on php include path or by extracting it into a specific folder (or user defind folder). Should be flexible enough.

3) I do not know code igniter itself. The solution you are looking for depends on whether code igniter behaves similar to zend framework (a simple library that can learn about common directory structures easy) or if it behaves like flow3 (only works with its own custom directory structure). So if it is acceptable that code igniter is in a very different folder (target/php-deps in php-maven or something similar) and your igniter webapp is in target/classes, you should always devide your custom files from code igniter files.

Comment: I am using a custom Maven solution (the project also contains some Java resources). Maven for PHP looks promising, I have not used it before. I will give it a try. Thank you for the pointers!